# LINQ Select New

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have DataTable that contains duplicate rows.
I need take this rows.
What I try to do

```
 Dim dups1 = From row In objDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable() _
                       Let UserId = row.Field(Of Integer)("UserId") _
                       Group row By UserId Into grp = Group _
                       Where (grp.Count() = 2) _
                       Select grp
```

but how i can to do Select New from this. I need

```
Select New UserName = row("UserName"), UserId = row("UserId")
```

how i can do this in first query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select an anonymous type

```
Select New With { .UserName = row.Field(Of String)("Username"), .UserId = row.Field(Of Integer)("UserId") }
```

Integrated in the query, assuming that the combination of `UserId` and `UserName` is unique:

```
Dim dups1 = From row In objDataSet.Tables(0).AsEnumerable()
            Group row By UserCols = New With {
                Key .UserId = row.Field(Of Integer)("UserId"),
                Key .UserName = row.Field(Of String)("Username")
            } Into Group
            Where Group.Count() > 1
            Select UserCols
```

Comment: How I can do this in first query ?

Comment: If use this version, i have an error "Count' is not a member of '<anonymous type>'; it does not exist in the current context." for UserCols.Count()

Comment: @undef.ms: sorry, fixed it.